# I am getting error "POST http://localhost:3001/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)"

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am new to node js and am developing a simple website. when sending an unregistered username to the server, instead of getting the "username/password does not exist", I am getting "POST http://localhost:3001/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)". can someone plz help me figure out this problem? thank you.

**my middleware**

[image]

**my Post request**

[image]

my route

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const {loginUser, registerUser} = 
require("../controllers/authController.js");

router.post('/register', registerUser);
router.post('/login', loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for ``/auth/login`` route? Paste code as text rather than image

Comment: On entering the username and password that does exists in the database, it throws "cannot set property 'user' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
    at registerUser (E:\coursework Updates\FYP\LilamiNepal\server\controllers\authController.js:19:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)" error

Comment: Can you specify where you are getting "POST http://localhost:3001/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)" if this is inside the console of your browser, can you check the network tab and see the actual response of the request? Are you parsing the body? There's too much missing information here to decide IMO

Comment: it is inside the browser's console, so I guess it is the response from the server?  and as for the response of the post request, I am getting the response that was inside of  the catch block of my middleware

Comment: If you are using Chrome, there's another tab called Network in the developer console, you can see all of the requests that your javascript inside the browser is making, can you check the response there? Also, you are logging the error object itself, if you want to log the response you have to use `console.error(error.response)` or `console.log(error.response)`

Comment: thank you so much, my error is finally being logged. as for the "login" POST request the response is {"message":"username/password doesnot exists"}.

Comment: If you post images of code, please also copy/paste or type the actual code directly into the post as text (within a code block). [Code in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which code is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I was using my route middleware before using the cookie and it was somehow throwing this error. sorry, for not providing the complete code, and thanks for all the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because you are not passing the `userdata` to the `login` function. I'm not sure but try using below code:

```
const login = (loginUser, loginPassword) => {
  axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', {
     username: loginUser,
     password: loginPassword
 }).then(...)
}
```

Comment: didnt work, thaks for reply

Comment: sorry it didn't work and no problem

Comment: and are you passing the data when you call the `login` function.

Comment: yes, it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You have a route issue! in you route you have:

```
router.post('/login', loginUser);
```

And in you test you have:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/login
```

So you need to either add `auth` in your route definition or remove `auth` in your axios post

Comment: i am using express router "app.use('/auth', authRoutes)" in my index.js file, so i dont think this is the problem

Comment: Your express route should be : ``router.post('/auth/login', loginUser);``

Comment: Ok, but you don't show the use in your code sample, so ...
provide all source code for maximized help

Comment: the same route is working for the signup though, and its not that I am not getting a response from the server, but I am only getting the message from the catch block of the middleware, even when the credentials are correct.

Comment: When you call the query function, try to pass parameter in an array:
``database.query(sqlSearch, [username]);``

Comment: thanks for the reply, and sorry for not providing with the complete code. it did not work.

Comment: Have you inspect ``user`` values in case of existing user in database?

Answer (score 0):

Many things can go wrong. I recommend you to just run the app with a debugger and just check line by line where something is wrong.
I see you are using Visual Studio Code. There are many Youtube videos on how to run the app with the debugger.